# Two clarifications on calculus of variations

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I'm currently studying calculus of variations.  I couldn't find a rigorous definition of a functional on this site.

1. What is the general definition of a functional?
2. Why for calculus of variations in physics, I must to use for a functional *a convex function* for the space of the admissible functions?

Comment: I recommend that you don't have $x$ on the left hand side, since the right hand side only depends on the function $y$, not on a specific value of $x$.

Comment: I suggest you try Wikipedia : (1), "Normed linear space" or "Normed vector space",  and (2) "Banach space",and  (3) "Linear functional" and "Bounded linear functional" and "Continuous linear functional".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's not what I'm looking for; thank you anyway.

Comment: @md2perpe I did not understand your answer.

Comment: My comment was about expressions like $\mathscr F(f(x))$. The functional $\mathscr F$ takes a *function* as argument, but when you write $\mathscr F(f(x))$ you apply $\mathscr F$ to the value $f(x)$. I know however that it's common, especially in physics, to be sloppy and write $\mathscr F(f(x))$ when the correct should be $\mathscr F(f)$.

Comment: I've tried to read what you've written in Italian, and although I don't know Italian, I've understood most of it. You seem to know what is a functional, but what is it you want to be explained? Are you looking for a derivation of the Euler-Lagrange differential equation?

Comment: @md2perpe During the college period, about 24 years ago, I never made a calculation of the variations and I'm trying, although I'm a secondary school teacher, I'm trying to write and fix the notes for the University of Modern Physics. I wonder if it is possible for you to give me an answer and to put in a rigorous and precise way what I have written. I thank you so much in advance. I have not yet studied brachythrocrones and I would like to understand how from a functional one it reaches the equations of Euler-Lagrange.

Comment: I see that you have changed your question to a completely different question. (Here is [revision 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2493481/2), [revision 9](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2493481/9), [revisions 10](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2493481/10); each of them different, but there is a major difference between 9 and 10.) Moreover, you have done this after receiving an answer. This is not a good thing to do. (I'd guess this should be self-evident.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'm making all the attempts to eliminate the block, because after two months I can not ask any questions. I still have not understood what I have to do. My English is very simple and I would like someone to help me unlock my account. I wrote to a moderator and in chat I clicked on the flag to get help. Until now I can not ask questions. Would you give me a valid help, please? I have always this message: You have reached your question limit Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: Thanks always for the downvote. I can not formulate, yet, any question. @egreg help me to delete my block editing my question. I'm very angry.

Comment: I've removed the part that doesn't belong in a question. Beyond that, I've undeleted one of your self-deleted questions. Currently, you're no longer question-banned, but you're still quite close to the threshold. Be careful when asking questions. Before asking any new question, be sure to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Make your questions clear, and provide context.

Comment: Hi Sir. I thank you very much for the help also for the elimination of the ban in this site. All right now I can ask a question. Greetings. Excuse me very much for the delay of my response due to long days of flu. Happy New Year.

Comment: @DanielFischer Excuse me again. I have again a block to ask a question. It is impossible. I do not know where to start because my studied combinational calculation theory is very limited. Excuse me again.

Comment: Question bans are automatic, they cannot be manually imposed or removed. Your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607487/how-many-numbers-consist-of-four-digits-whose-sum-is-7) was again originally asked without context, so it's no wonder that it was downvoted and gathered close votes. In [revisions 4 and 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2607487/revisions), you had a bit of context, but you removed that after the question was closed. Instead of removing it, it would have been better to expand on it.

Comment: For example the notation $C^{(r)}_{k,n}$ is not universally known. You should have explained what it means. You could have mentioned _where_ you have seen the three formulas, and asked for an explanation _why_ they solve the problem. If you edit the question to provide such context, that might cause it to be reopened. And that _might_ end the ban. It's worth trying, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a functional?

As it is well written in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)), a functional simply refers to a mapping from a space $X$ into the real numbers. (Technically one might refer to other [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) as well. But we can safely restrict our attention to the real numbers here.) Depending on the authors, such maps may or may not be linear. Consider the following example in the context of calculus of variations.

Suppose $U\subset{\bf R}^n$ is a bounded open set with smooth boundary $\partial U$ and we are given a smooth function (the Lagrangian)
$$
L:{\bf R}^n\times{\bf R}\times\overline{U}\to{\bf R}.
$$

We define a map $I$ with
$$
I[w]:=\int_U L(Dw(x),w(x),x)\ dx
$$
for smooth functions $w:\overline{U}\to{\bf R}$ satisfying, say, the boundary condition
$$
w=g\quad\text{on }\partial U.
$$

Now let $X$ be the set of smooth functions $w:\overline{U}\to{\bf R}$ such that $w=g$ on $\partial U$. Then the map $I$ is a **functional** mapping from $X$ to ${\bf R}$.

---

> Convexity (of the Lagrangian)?

The basic idea of calculus of variation can be summarized as follows: instead of solving a (nonlinear) PDE $A(u)=0$ directly, one associates it with some appropriate "energy" functional $I$ by writing $A$ as the "derivative" of $I$. Symbolically, we write
$$
A(\cdot)=I'[\cdot].
$$
Then the PDE $A(u)=0$ reads as $I'[u]=0$. This new formulation allows us to recognize solutions of $A(u)=0$ as being **critical points** of the functional $I[\cdot]$. *If* the functional $I[\cdot]$ has a minimum at $u$, then presumably $I'[u]=0$ is valid and thus $u$ is a solution of the original PDE.

On the other hand, one needs some conditions on the Lagrangian $L$ which ensure that the functional $I[\cdot]$ does indeed have a minimizer within an appropriate function space (the class of "admissible" functions). It turns out that one of the conditions we need is the **convexity** of $L$ (which together with some other assumptions imply the "weak lower semicontinuity" of the functional $I$, which allows us to take limits in a compactness argument). The convexity assumption of $L$ can be also seen by the *second variation* of $I[\cdot]$ at the function $u$.

For more technical mathematical details, see the first two sections in Chapter 8 of Evans's *[Partial Differential Equations](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r)*.

---

<sup>Note: This question has been edited quite a few times. This is an answer to the [current version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2493481/24).</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. II hope I can answer you in detail about what you wrote. I do not generally trust Wikipedia, but I should find some free time to write something in Italian and translate it into English. Obviously the symbology is not unique for the whole world of mathematicians. Remember that I did not calculate variations in my life.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You are welcome. Except the second paragraph "As it is well written... ", everything I wrote is essentially from Evans's book. Wikipedia is a good place to check new concepts. But they have also explicitly said that ["We do not expect you to trust us"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ten_things_you_may_not_know_about_Wikipedia#We_do_not_expect_you_to_trust_us) `:)` Alternatively, you may check https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Functional

Comment: @Sebastiano I was once told that "It’s worth bearing in mind that notation (symbols) is ultimately an artificial human invention, rather than an innate feature of the mathematics one is working on". So yes, "Obviously the 'symbology' is not unique for the whole world of mathematicians." and I would add that this is in particular very true in the field of PDE.

Comment: Excuse me Jack again? Why for my question I have always upvote?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr F$ be a functional of the form
$$\mathscr F(y) = \int_a^b f(x, y(x), y'(x)) \, dx.$$

We want to find a function $y_0$ that gives a local minimum of $\mathscr F,$ i.e. if we take a "close" function $y_0+\delta y$ then $\mathscr F(y_0+\delta y)$ will not be as small.

The idea is to let $\delta y = \lambda\eta,$ where $\eta$ is some function that is non-zero only in a small region and $\lambda$ is a real parameter. For a fixed $\eta$, then $\mathscr F(y_0+\lambda\eta)$ is a function of $\lambda$ which should have minimum for $\lambda=0.$

Therefore we take the derivative of $\mathscr F(y_0+\lambda\eta)$:
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathscr F(y_0+\lambda\eta)
= \frac{d}{d\lambda} \int_a^b f(x, y_0(x)+\lambda\eta(x), y_0'(x)+\lambda\eta'(x)) \, dx \\
= \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} f(x, y_0(x)+\lambda\eta(x), y_0'(x)+\lambda\eta'(x)) \, dx \\
= \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdots) \, \eta(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(\cdots) \, \eta'(x) \right) \, dx \\
$$
where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second argument (which is $y(x)$ in the defining equation for $\mathscr F$) and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its third argument (which is $y'(x)$ in the defining equation for $\mathscr F$). Also, $(\cdots)$ stands for $(x, y_0(x)+\lambda\eta(x), y_0'(x)+\lambda\eta'(x)).$

Now we use partial integration to remove the derivative from $\eta'(x)$:
$$
\int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdots) \, \eta(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(\cdots) \, \eta'(x) \right) \, dx \\
= \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdots) \, \eta(x) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(\cdots)\right) \, \eta(x) \right) \, dx \\
= \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdots) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(\cdots)\right) \right) \, \eta(x) \, dx
$$
if $\eta(a) = \eta(b) = 0$ (remember that we said that $\eta$ should be non-zero only in a small region).

We shall have a minimum for $\lambda=0$ so
$$
0 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathscr F(y_0+\lambda\eta)
= \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y_0(x), y_0'(x)) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(x, y_0(x), y_0'(x))\right) \right) \, \eta(x) \, dx
$$

This shall be valid for any choice of $\eta$ which requires
$$0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y_0(x), y_0'(x)) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(x, y_0(x), y_0'(x))\right)$$

Why so? Because if the above expression isn't $0$ everywhere then there exists some interval where it is non-zero (say positive), and then we can take $\eta$ to be positive inside that interval and zero outside of it. Such an $\eta$ would make the integral non-zero, and we get a contradiction.

Comment: Very kind I have read your answer and I vote you. At this period I am arrived to undestand the space of the ammissible function and around strong and weak. Can I ask if I can edit your answer and try to make me understand step by step what you have wrote? I have never studied at the university (22 years ago) calculating the variations. Also if I could ask you if I could edit my question to make it more clear to users. I think many did not understand what I asked. On the site I did not find the functional definition in the classic case and in the general case. Thank you very much.

Comment: You may edit both my and your question. I propose that you don't remove anything but just add things, e.g. comments.

Comment: The meaning of $\partial f/\partial y$ (and $\partial f/\partial y'$) does not look very clear to me as $y$ is not a number but a function. How do we know that this notation makes sense?

Comment: @pluton. The meanings are "derivative of $f$ w.r.t. the variable which has been replace with the function $y$ (*viz.* $y'$)". It's in the same spirit as when writing the chain rule of $f(g(x))$ as $df/dg \cdot dg/dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rigorous definition:
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb K$.
Then every function $F:V\to\mathbb K$ is called a functional.

An important class of functionals are linear functionals.
If $\mathbb K\in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$ and $V$ is a normed vector space ( or even a topological vector space)
then the continuous linear functionals are important objects.

Comment: I have never studied functional or general calculation of variations. I understand what you have written to me, but it is not useful to me for what I'm studying in the Foundations of Modern Physics. I do not have to use standardized spaces. I would be interested in understanding the case where the argument function is $f(x, y, y ', y' ', \ldots)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n $. I rightly vote +1 your answer because whoever makes available his time should always thank him or thank her. And do not vote like some users -1 without even leaving a comment on why.

Comment: i answered your question. If the answer was not helpful for you, then maybe you can make a new question where you ask your actual question including the additional details that you mention.

Comment: I add others details. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do we really require $V$ to be a vector space in the definition? Suppose we want to find the real-valued function $f$ continuous on $[1, 3]$ that maximizes a functional $F$, then $F: C_{[1, 3]} \to \mathbb{R}$ but the continuous functions on $[1, 3]$ do not constitute a vector space.

Comment: @Pakchoiandbacon that is wrong, the continuous functions on $[1,3]$ do constitute a vector space.

Comment: Right! I'm sorry, you're right I was too quick thinking 0 wasn't in there but the zero function is of course continuous on $[1, 3]$.